# Active Storage: Best practice to retain/cache uploaded file when form redisplays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

When uploading files with Active Storage, when a file is finished uploading and the form gets redisplayed, for example when the validation for that form fails for some reason, the file is gone.

Is there a way to cache or retain it between form redisplays? [Shrine has a nice Plugin](https://shrinerb.com/rdoc/classes/Shrine/Plugins/CachedAttachmentData) for that purpose, I'm looking for something similar for Active Storage.

Comment: Did you manage to do something about this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still sticking with Shrine, which works great and has some other great features Active Storage is still missing, like uploading files as data URIs.

Comment: @cseelus what's wrong with the solution dmitry posted below? I know it will stop working in Rails 6, but it works. And it can easily be removed when 6.0 drops next year.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a solution to make ActiveStorage files persist on form redisplay:

`f.hidden_field :image, value: f.object.image.signed_id if f.object.image.attached?
f.file_field :image`

Comment: Dmitry I want to buy you many beers right now, you saved my sanity! Thanks!

Comment: For anyone who wants to use this, be aware that this is unfortunately not compatible with new changes in Rails master, that store newly-uploaded files on save rather than assignment https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/33303

Comment: Fortunately, that breaking change will be part of Rails 6, which is only a distant future.

Comment: Rails 5.2.1 now has the signed_id value : )

Comment: If anyone has a solution for this issue in Rails 6, please answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649565/when-using-activestorage-in-rails-6-how-do-i-retain-a-file-when-redisplaying-a

Comment: When I tried this, I receive a `ActiveSupport::MessageVerifier::InvalidSignature` exception (Rails 6.1.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

for those looking for `has_many_attached` solution

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/35817#issuecomment-484158884

```
<% if @product.photos.attached? %>
  <% @product.photos.each do |ph| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :photos, value: ph.signed_id %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: where in the Rails API docs are you seeing that the hidden_field helper accepts a "multiple: true" option?  Also I'm unaware of the HTML spec allowing such an attribute on inputs

Comment: sorry this is probably a typo (you are right multiple is not an option + multiple is not needed as I'm looping through the photos with #each) let mi fixit.  ( `multilple: true` removed)

Comment: With Rails 7.0.4, **it didn't work without** `multiple: true`. Thanks.