# When using activestorage in Rails 6, how do I retain a file when redisplaying a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-6

In Rails 6 I have a form with a file field and I am using activestorage to store the file. If validations fail after submitting the form, the form is redisplayed showing the validation errors. How can I retain the file added to the file field when redisplaying the form so that the user does not have to add the file again to the form?

There is already a similar question for rails 5: [Active Storage: Best practice to retain/cache uploaded file when form redisplays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360307/active-storage-best-practice-to-retain-cache-uploaded-file-when-form-redisplays), however the solution there only applies to Rails 5.

Comment: You said "however the solution there only applies to Rails 5". Do you have any error?

Comment: The comments in the post he linked to explains - rails 6 no longer stores the file on assignment but on save, meaning the technique used there won't have access to the required file

Comment: Oops, my bad. Maybe you should consider to use a model to save attachments before the record's validation, then attach them to the record when it's saved?

Comment: Anyone have an answer for how to do this WITHOUT using `direct_upload`? I really dislike what we have to do to open up CORS to make that work.

Answer (score 7):

Since Rails 6 does not store the file on assignment, the workaround I found was to enable direct upload on the file field. This will upload the file via javascript before the form submission.

```
= f.file_field :doc, direct_upload: true
```

For this to work, you also need to add activestorage.js to your bundle as described in the [Active Storage guide](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#direct-upload-installation).

After that change one can use the method described in the question [Active Storage: Best practice to retain/cache uploaded file when form redisplays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50360307/active-storage-best-practice-to-retain-cache-uploaded-file-when-form-redisplays). That means adding the signed_id to your form in a hidden field as follows:

```
= f.file_field :doc, direct_upload: true
= f.hidden_field :doc, value: f.object.doc.signed_id if f.object.doc.attached?
```

Comment: Shouldn't the hidden field come first? https://youtu.be/mG1BUMuSmsc?t=577

Comment: This doesn't work when editing an item that already has an attachment. It will retain the existing attachment.

Comment: Robban answer does work for me (even without the direct_upload). This article explains this answer further:

https://medium.com/@TETRA2000/active-storage-how-to-retain-uploaded-files-on-form-resubmission-91b57be78d53

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Robban answer, for multiple attachments, and doing some previewing

```
  = f.file_field :attachments, multiple: true, direct_upload: true
  - f.object.attachments.each do |attach|
    = f.hidden_field :attachments, value: attach.signed_id, multiple: true
    = image_tag attach.preview(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) if attach.previewable?
    = image_tag attach.variant(resize_to_limit: [100, 100]) if attach.variable?
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to store file with form post (without direct upload). But it requires additional code to the usual scaffolded code `@mention = Mention.create(mention_params)`

controller code:

```
@mention.screenshot.blob.upload(mention_params[:screenshot])
@mention.screenshot.blob.save
```

while debugging check that it creates a record in active_storage_blob table.

Once file uploaded you can reuse signed_id on next submissions (when model validation does not pass).

view code:

```
f.hidden_field :screenshot, value: ...screenshot.signed_id if ...screenshot.attached? %>
```

It is not a clean solution but I think you'll get the point.